# Black screen after changing systemctl

Tags: boot, refind

I wanted to start my MacBook running Linux Mint laptop in terminal mode, so I searched the internet and found this command: `systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

After running that command and rebooting, it started normally but ended in a black screen. It looks like it turned off my screen and I can enter my rEFInd boot menu and I can change boot options from there, but I don't now how this works. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to return to the original state by running

`systemctl set-default graphical.target`

If you are not even able to boot, you could try adding this boot option/argument

`systemd.unit=graphical.target`

Comment: I was able to get into the terminal and enter the first command, thanks :)